# How to make nine cells side by side in collection view [Xcode] [Swift 3]

Tags: swift, xcode, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have never worked with collection view before and although there are several tutorials I didn't find the answer on my questions.
I use a collection view inside a ViewController, not inside a CollectionViewController.

I want to make an special number of cells (in my project: nine) side by side.
But I want to have borders around the cells (eventually they could be have a different thickness, but that is not important).

Can anybody help me?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This will help you to get started with horizontal scrolling [Creating a horizontal scrolling collectionview in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39946022/creating-a-horizontal-scrolling-collectionview-in-swift)

For setting of the cell you will need to implement UICollectionViewDelegate and method (here you can set your cell with data):

```
func dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier identifier: String, for indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
```

just do not forget to register nib or class for cell otherwise it will not work(you do not need to do it in code, if you add the cell to the collection view in storyboard)

Comment: I am not completely new with this.
I have worked several times with tableViews and I can program it.
I have made a good working program with a working collection view `UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, UITextFieldDelegate`, but the problem is: how can I format it, that nine cells are side by side.

Comment: ok so then set `collectionViewFlowLayout.scrollDirection = .horizontal`

Answer (score 0):

Tell me if this can help you.

I don't use Storyboard.

AppDelegate.swift

```
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.

        window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal

        let nineCellsController = NineCellsController(collectionViewLayout: layout)

        window?.rootViewController = nineCellsController
        return true
    }
```

NineCellsController.swift

```
import UIKit

class NineCellsController: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    let cellIdentifier = "cellIdentifier"
    let numberOfCells = 9

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        collectionView?.backgroundColor = .white

        setupCollectionView()    
    }

    func setupCollectionView() {
        collectionView?.register(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier)
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return numberOfCells
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath)
        cell.backgroundColor = randomColor()
        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: view.frame.size.width, height: view.frame.size.height)
    }

    fileprivate func randomColor() -> UIColor {
        let red = CGFloat(drand48())
        let green = CGFloat(drand48())
        let blue = CGFloat(drand48())
        return UIColor(red: red, green: green, blue: blue, alpha: 1)
    }
}
```