# How to change the direction of filling the UICollectionView?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uicollectionview

I would like to know how to change the direction of filling the UICollectionView when the scrolling direction is horizontal. The UICollectionView has 2 rows and 5 columns that are filled up from a one-dimensional array. Thanks.

[Horizontal scrolling with vertical filling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KEm1R.png)

[Vertical scrolling with Horizontal filling](https://ibb.co/k2QsMbG)

Comment: Any design image

Comment: try `collectionView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: -1, y: 1)`

Comment: I have find the answer for my question: [How to change the direction of filling the UICollectionView?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39951962/8219058)

Answer (score 0):

> We can do same Springboard behavior using UICollectionView and for
>   that, we need to write code for a custom layout.  My friend has
>   achieved it with custom layout class implementation with
>   [SMCollectionViewFillLayout](https://github.com/smindia1988/SMCollectionViewFillLayout).